# I cannot get the trafficService from platform

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to get the trafficService from H.service.Platform, but for some reason I can't

I'm following the documentation:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-service-traffic-service.html

So I have a working H.service.Platform (that's working for sure, because i'm using the TrafficIncidentsService and zero problems).

But when I try to get the trafficService exaclty as described in the docs

```
let traffic = platform.getTrafficService();
```

All I got is an error

````
ERROR TypeError: platform.getTrafficService is not a function
at HereTrafficApiService.getTrafficFlow (here-traffic-api.service.ts:37)
at TrafficWidgetComponent.getApiData (traffic-widget.component.ts:219)
    at traffic-widget.component.ts:62
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:454)
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2650)```
````

Maybe i'm missing something but, if I look into the platform object from the inspector there is a *getTrafficIncidentsService()* **but** no *getTrafficService()* and i can't figure out why.
Can someone help?

Comment: Can you please add more code showing how the you instantiate Platform and which version of the API you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using version 3.0, then there is no service to show traffic flow tiles, as traffic flow tiles are part of MapTileService. Therefore:

**version 3.0:**

traffic tiles: `platform.getMapTileService()`

traffic incidents: `platform.getTrafficIncidents()`

**version 3.1:**

traffic tiles & incidents: `platform.getTrafficService()`